# using iphone to trigger events on a Mac

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, remote-access, launchd

Is there any sample code/open source code available on how you could trigger events on a Mac with an iOS device ? What I want is for me to say click a button on the iOS app and this triggers some event on the MAC which could be running a daemon listening for this trigger  ?
Any ideas ? I am interested in writing this just for learning purposes. I am going along the lines of maybe I need to design my own small protocol that both the daemon and the iOS app can understand and then communicate with each other. ANy other recommended approaches ?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a small web server process to run on the Mac and accept calls through a custom REST-based API.